# Automatic subtract number without button click based on input using javascript or PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have more than 2 inputs that can only accept numbers and there is a displayed number on the top. How could I subtract the numbers that I have entered just by changing the value on any of the input boxes? Please Help.

```
 <p id='Answer'> 100 </p>
 <input type='number' max='10' min='0' name='num1'>
 <input type='number' max='5' min='0' name='num2'>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok your question is a little ambiguous. Anyway I have assumed you want the following. You want the num1 to subtract automatically from num2 and be displayed in id='Answer'.

Following is the code to that in jQuery.

```
$(".sub").focusout(function() {
  $("#answer").html('');
  var num1 = $("#num1").val();
  var num2 = $("#num2").val();
  var answer = num1 - num2;
  $("#answer").html(answer);
});
```

You can view the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Z5dV8/) here

In case you want both input fields to subtract from 100. Following is the code.

```
$(".sub").focusout(function() {
$("#answer").html('');
var num1 = $("#num1").val();
var num2 = $("#num2").val();
var answer = 100 - num1 - num2;
$("#answer").html(answer);
});
```

And following is the link to [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Z5dV8/1/)

Based on your question in last comment. Download jquery from [here](http://jquery.com/download/). Now include the downloaded script in your header. Or just use the following code.

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
```

After you have included jquery you need to use your .focusout code like stated below

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(".sub").focusout(function() {
     $("#answer").html('');
     var num1 = $("#num1").val();
     var num2 = $("#num2").val();
     var answer = 100 - num1 - num2;
     $("#answer").html(answer);
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks. But I need for both inputs to be able to subtract "100" at the same time. For example I have entered "3" on my first input and "2" on my second. They both are subtracted to 100 automatically which will result to "95" as the answer. :) Sorry for being a noob. Im still learning how to do stuff like this :)

Comment: You mean subtract from 100? Please see the new code. This should do the trick. It will subtract when you focusout from any input field. In case you want to do it only when it focuses out from the second input field let me know so I can change the code accordingly.

Comment: Wow ! Thanks. :) Uhm .. One more thing though. Could you teach how I could use this Jquery code and attach it to my HTML ? hehe. What should I put on my header ? :)

Comment: I have edited the code above. This is quite basic so I would recommend going over a couple of more tutorials so that you understand a little better.

Answer (score 2):

Try this code. It works cool.

```
<p id='Answer'> 100 </p>
<input type='number' max='10' min='0' id='num1' value="0">
<input type='number' max='5' min='0'  id='num2' value="0">

<script>

    $("#num2").keyup(function(){
        $("#answer").html('');
        var n1 = $("#num1").val();
        var n2 = $("#num2").val();
        var ans = n1 - n2;
        $("#answer").html(ans);
    }); 
    $("#num1").keyup(function(){
        $("#answer").html('');
        var n1 = $("#num1").val();
        var n2 = $("#num2").val();
        var ans = n1 - n2;
        $("#answer").html(ans);
    });
</script>
```

Pls check this http://jsfiddle.net/P7FNs/2/

Answer (score 0):

```
<p id='Answer'> 100 </p>
<input type='number' max='10' min='0' id='num1' value="0">
<input type='number' max='5' min='0'  id='num2' value="0">

<script>
    var input1_ = document.getElementById('num1');
    var input2_ = document.getElementById('num2');
    var answer = document.getElementById('Answer');
    function sub(){
        answer.innerHTML = (parseInt(input1_.value) - parseInt(input2_.value));
    }
    document.getElementById('num1').onkeyup = function () {
        sub();
    };
    document.getElementById('num2').onkeyup = function () {
        sub();
    };
</script>
```